# How to decompose seasonality of a time series with a limited time span?

Tags: r, time-series, python, multiple-seasonalities, decomposition

I am working on a time series that contains daily sales data over 2 and a half years. The aim of the project is to estimate the impact of marketing expenditure on the sales, while accounting for seasonality and trend.

A plot of the data reveals a strong weekly seasonality. There also seems to be yearly seasonality. However, as there is only 2 and a half years of data available, I was wondering what the best method(s) would be to take the yearly seasonality into account without sacrificing too much of the data for testing the impact of marketing expenditure on?

I am more confortable in Python, but if need be I can use R as well.

Comment: You may want to look at [TBATS models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/tbats/info), although their original form (and the implementation in the `forecast` package for R) does not allow for covariates, like your marketing expenditures. Maybe you can remove the multiple seasonalities using a TBATS model, then regress the deseasonalized series on marketing expenditure.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. Looking into TBATS I found a [blog post](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tbats-with-regressors/) from Hyndsight suggesting to use auto.arima with multiple Fourier terms as covariates for the double seasonality. I will try out both and see what works best!